# Array.push updates itself while using inside map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Here I have used two new arrays for catching URL and Filename value. When I view it on console I got different values everytime like array got overwritten from previous values, Am I doing anything wrong?

```
downLoadFilesAsZip = async(item) => {

for (const index in item.docLinks) {
  let urlArr=[];
  let fileNameArr = [];
  const url = item.docLinks[index];
  let linkParts = url.split("?");
  let filename = linkParts[0].substring(linkParts[0].lastIndexOf('/')+1);
  urlArr.push(url);
  fileNameArr.push(filename);  
}
}

downLoadAllAsZip = () => {
  {
    this.state.docGroups.length !== 0 && this.state.docGroups.map((item) => {
      if(item.docLinks !== null && item.docLinks.length > 0){
          return(
            this.downLoadFilesAsZip(item)
          );
      }
    })
  }  
}
```

Comment: `for (...) { let urlArr = []; urlArr.push(); }` - Why should this work (do anything useful)?

Comment: Any statement within the `for (...) { ... }` block will be executed for each iteration. So, for each `index`, new empty arrays named `urlArr` andd `fileNameArr` are created. If the objective is to collect items from itm.dockLinks, the two arrays must be declared as empty before the for loop. Also, once these arrays have the values, the info needs to be stored or returned. Otherwise, once control flows outside of the async function, the arrays are no longer defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the loop. Every time your loop runs you are setting empty arrays.

```
let urlArr=[];
let fileNameArr = [];
```

bring that outside of your for loop.

Comment: Thanks I'm still new to functionality as I'm a frontend dev. This helped.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring array outside for loop(after import) helped to update every values,
For .tsx file answer was this

```
type urlArr = any[];
type fileNameArr = any[];
let urlArr=[];
let fileNameArr = [];
```